# Cosine similarity of a new text document with existing list of documents

Tags: python, text, nlp, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe of 1000 text documents with corresponding keywords.I want to extract keywords of a new document by finding the keywords corresponding to the documents in the list which is most similar.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible problem that we can investigate. You can find some helpful tips on asking questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First save your csv to a dataframe df and use the below functions for cosine similarity calculation.
    def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

```
sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

if not denominator:
    return 0.0
else:
    return float(numerator) / denominator

def text_to_vector(text):
word = re.compile(r'\w+')
words = word.findall(text)
return Counter(words)

def get_result(content_a, content_b):
text1 = content_a
text2 = content_b

vector1 = text_to_vector(text1)
vector2 = text_to_vector(text2)

cosine_result = get_cosine(vector1, vector2)
return cosine_result
```

Then iterate over the df and invoke the functions as below:

```
similarity=[]
for ind in df.index:
#my_doc="new document should go in here"
#prev_doc= "previous document for each index should go in here"
cos=get_result(my_doc, prev_doc)
similarity.append(cos)
max_ind= similarity.index(max(similarity))
```

## You will get the index position of the most similar document